# How to create a UINavigationControll in UIViewController programmatically Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I´m creating a multiScene app for iOS in Swift Storyboard.
I want to add a UINavigationController programmatically in UIViewController or if there is possible with storyboard, I have made a lot a research for this and I haven´t find anything valuable.

[In each view controller I want to add the Navigation Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUuVs.png)

Also I have create one but is not responsible for all phones and the button does not work

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let height: CGFloat = 50
    let width = self.view.frame.width
    let navbar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: width, height: height))
    navbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    navbar.delegate = self

    let navItem = UINavigationItem()
    navItem.title = "Last Call"
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add New", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)

    navbar.items = [navItem]

    view.addSubview(navbar)

    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height, width: width, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height - height))

}
```

I have embed a Navigation controller in my view controller and this is how it looks like
[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KotZy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look at "Showing and Hiding View Controllers" where some navigation concepts are explained: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/showing_and_hiding_view_controllers

When using storyboards you should be able to use a segue to navigate from one view controller to another.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you want, but let me explain a few things:

1. You can't add a `UINavigationController` directly in a `UIViewController`, we wrap the `ViewController` instead:

   ```
   let viewController = some ViewController //your ViewController
   let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)//this becomes the ViewController to be used. 
   self.present(navigationController)//example of usage
   ```
2. We don't wrap every `UIViewController` in `UINavigationController`, only the navigation parents.

Comment: So I want to create a navigation controller so then I can add e button in navigation controller

Comment: I put your code in a function and call it in my view did load but it didn't work

Comment: As mentioned above, you cannot do that.  You need to add it when presenting that `ViewController` not in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: This view controller that i want to add the Navigation controller opens when i click in a cell of table view controller